# Terraform error argument named is not expected here for azurerm_lb

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-load-balancer

I am running below code , getting argument not expected here ,but the arguments are there in the terraform document . Please  advise.
variables.tf file

```
      type = list(object(
        {
          lb_name                       = string
          sku                           = string
          location                      = string
          lb_resource_group_name        = string
          vnet_name                     = string
          vnet_resource_group_name      = string
          subnet_name                   = string
          frontend_ip_config            = list(object({
                                            frontend_ip_name    = string
                                            private_ip_address  = string
                                          }))
            }
  ))
  description = "lb creation"
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "lb" {
  for_each            = { for lb in var.load_balancer : lb.lb_name => lb }
  name                = each.value.lb_name
  sku                 = each.value.sku
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.lb_resource_group_name

  dynamic "frontend_ip_configuration" {
    for_each                      = { for fip in each.value.frontend_ip_config : fip.frontend_ip_name => fip }
    name                          = frontend_ip_configuration.value.frontend_ip_name
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.value.lb_name].id  
    private_ip_address            = frontend_ip_configuration.value.private_ip_address
    private_ip_address_allocation = frontend_ip_configuration.value.private_ip_address == null ? "Dynamic" : "Static"
  }
}
```

Error

```
"msg": "Failed to validate Terraform configuration files:\r\n\u001b[31m╷\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\u001b[1m\u001b[31mError: \u001b[0m\u001b[0m\u001b[1mUnsupported argument\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\u001b[0m  on private-link-module/private-link-service.tf line 17, in resource \"azurerm_lb\" \"lb\":\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m  17:     \u001b[4mname\u001b[0m                          = frontend_ip_configuration.value.frontend_ip_name\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0mAn argument named \"name\" is not expected here.\n\u001b[31m╵\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m╷\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\u001b[1m\u001b[31mError: \u001b[0m\u001b[0m\u001b[1mUnsupported argument\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\u001b[0m  on private-link-module/private-link-service.tf line 18, in resource \"azurerm_lb\" \"lb\":\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m  18:     \u001b[4msubnet_id\u001b[0m                     = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.value.lb_name].id  \u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0mAn argument named \"subnet_id\" is not expected here.\n\u001b[31m╵\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m╷\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\u001b[1m\u001b[31mError: \u001b[0m\u001b[0m\u001b[1mUnsupported argument\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\u001b[0m  on private-link-module/private-link-service.tf line 19, in resource \"azurerm_lb\" \"lb\":\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m  19:     \u001b[4mprivate_ip_address\u001b[0m            = frontend_ip_configuration.value.private_ip_address\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0mAn argument named \"private_ip_address\" is not expected here.\n\u001b[31m╵\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m╷\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\u001b[1m\u001b[31mError: \u001b[0m\u001b[0m\u001b[1mUnsupported argument\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\u001b[0m  on private-link-module/private-link-service.tf line 20, in resource \"azurerm_lb\" \"lb\":\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m  20:     \u001b[4mprivate_ip_address_allocation\u001b[0m = frontend_ip_configuration.value.private_ip_address == null ? \"Dynamic\" : \"Static\"\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0m\n\u001b[31m│\u001b[0m \u001b[0mAn argument named \"private_ip_address_allocation\" is not expected here.\n\u001b[31m╵\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n",
```

Provider version:
version = "2.98.0"

terraform version : "~> 1.1.7"

Comment: What version of the provider are you using?

Comment: Provider version: version = "2.98.0"

terraform version : "~> 1.1.7"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about `content`. it should be:

```
  dynamic "frontend_ip_configuration" {
    for_each                      = { for fip in each.value.frontend_ip_config : fip.frontend_ip_name => fip }

    content { 
      name                          = frontend_ip_configuration.value.frontend_ip_name
      subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet[frontend_ip_configuration.value.lb_name].id  
      private_ip_address            = frontend_ip_configuration.value.private_ip_address
      private_ip_address_allocation = frontend_ip_configuration.value.private_ip_address == null ? "Dynamic" : "Static"
   }
 
  }
```